# "I will make me a ..." or "I will make myself a ..."

Tags: grammar, phrases

Is the first form valid as well, or only the second?

E.g. "I will make me a sandwich"

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not clear to me how this is a duplicate of that question, which is more about a specific instance where it's OK to use “me” in a reflexive context, and I don't think that applies here.

Comment: *I will make me a sandwich* is typically used humorously to suggest the speaker is so hungry his mental faculties have diminished to the point he is unable to form grammatical sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I will make myself...** is correct.

I can't think of any sentence at all where **I will make me** would be grammatically correct.

Here's why: "Myself" is the reflexive form of "me", for use when you've already used the pronoun (in this case, "I") in the sentence and are referring back to it. For example, I'd say "you can make a sandwich for yourself", rather than "you can make a sandwich for you", since I already referred to you (by using the word "you") in the sentence.

Comment: *I will make me...* is not standard English, but it is not uncommon in colloquial situations, particularly in the form  *I'm gonna make me...*.

Comment: Sure, I definitely wouldn't disagree that it could be dialectical or colloquial. It's not grammatically correct or even wrong-but-accepted, though.

Comment: @Yee-Lum It is entirely grammatical and entirely correct except in the handful of dialects - Academic English and Broadcast Pundit English, for instance - where it is not.

Answer (score 1):

**I will make me**, means I will make something for me.. A sandwich, a cake ect.

**I will make myself**, means I will put myself in a position to be.. available, ready, ect.

Comment: I've never heard the first one used seriously by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The second form is valid.  Also valid is:

"I will make a sandwich for myself"

Answer (score 0):

"I will make me a sandwich" sounds at best unnatural to my ear -- at worst ungrammatical -- as long as you make a sandwich for someone, but definitely make a sandwich for yourself.

And so:

> Can you make me a sandwich?
>
> Can you make a sandwich for me?

But, use a reflexive pronoun if and when you want to emphasize that the subject does the action.

> I'll make myself a sandwich.
>
> I'll make a sandwich for myself.